# accelerating a macroscopic object to relativistic speed

Tags: soft-question

Is there science and technology available today that would, in principle, allow accelerating a macroscopic object to relativistic speeds?

Comment: What bounds do you want for "Relativistic speeds" ?

Comment: I would say something like ~50% of speed of light would count as relativistic

Comment: The Breakthrough Starshot project aims at 20%t of lightspeed using laser propelled micro-probes. Still mostly on the drawing board, but seriously intended as doable within 20 years or so.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakthrough_Starshot